# When the RAM is used up, what will happen?

Tags: swap, ram, tmp

When I ran ImageMagick's `convert` to convert and combine image files into a pdf file, 
it will create 10GB temporary dirs and files in `/tmp`.

I am not sure if it did that all the time, or because my RAM was used up. Some said that `convert` did it because my RAM had no more free space.

In general, what happens when the RAM is used up? Doesn't the OS
 swap the content of Ram to the swap partition on the disk?

But is the swap partition in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the swap partition is it's own partition, or a file on the filesystem.

It certainly won't just start writing to a file in /tmp of its own will.

If you run the command "free -m" that will show you both how much RAM & SWAP you have, and how much is being used.

Whilst your process is running it will be worth running a "watch free -m" and keep an eye on the memory usage to ascertain what is happening on your system.